# Stop Spyder from opening the underlying file when in debug mode

Tags: python, spyder

I run my script in Spyder.  It finds an error.  I click the Stop button.  Spyder will open the underlying python file that caused the error.  How do I stop this from happening?

I have gone through the settings and google, but I cannot find out how to stop this.

What I want is when there is an error, I click the stop button, nothing further happens other than the code has exited debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

You could disable that behavior by changing Run preferences:

1. Tools->Preferences
2. On left menu choose “Run” then locate “General settings” section then uncheck "Directly enter debugging when errors appear."
3. Apply

:)

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion.  A clarification.  I WANT to enter debug mode if an error occurs.  Because then I can manually try out code to see if it fixes the error.  What I don't want is after I fix the code, I hit stop button for the script, and then some other script opens (base.py, sql.py, range.py, etc.).